# Understanding reflection in django for refactoring

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, reflection, refactoring

I am working on my first Django project and I need to understand the way reflection is used in django.

- I have the method `category_autocomplete` which I use with jQuery to get autocomplete for a category field.
- I need autocomplete in some more places but on different things. I think it might be a good idea to make into a class for reuse.
- I have started making the class but I am not sure how to proceed.

The problem is the way django uses the `filter` function. It has a parameter which goes like `<param-name>_icontains`. I can easily reproduce the lambda by using `getattr` and passing parameter name as a string but I cannot figure out how to use reflection to get the parameter name for the `filter` function.

Any idea how this can be done?

```
class Autocomplete():
    @staticmethod
    def get_json_autocomplete(self, cur_objects, func):
        results = []
        for cur_object in cur_objects:
            results.append(func(cur_object))
        return json.dumps(results)

    @staticmethod
    def autocomplete(self, request, class_name, attr_name):
        term = request.GET.get('term', '')
        data = Autocomplete.get_json_autocomplete(
            #Problem here
            class_name.objects.filter(attr_name=term),
            lambda x: getattr(x, attr_name)
        )
        return HttpResponse(data, 'application/json')

def _get_json_autocomplete(cur_objects, func):
    results = []
    for cur_object in cur_objects:
        results.append(func(cur_object))
    return json.dumps(results)

def category_autocomplete(request):
    term = request.GET.get('term', '')
    data = _get_json_autocomplete(
        Category.objects.filter(name__icontains=term),
        lambda x: x.name
    )
    return HttpResponse(data, 'application/json')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I believe you're looking for is `**`, take a look [here](http://www.nomadjourney.com/2009/04/dynamic-django-queries-with-kwargs/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters).

So that part of your code could be:

```
def autocomplete(self, request, class_name, attr_name):
    term = request.GET.get('term', '')
    data = Autocomplete.get_json_autocomplete(
        class_name.objects.filter(**{attr_name + '__icontains': term}),
        lambda x: getattr(x, attr_name)
    )
    return HttpResponse(data, 'application/json')
```

Comment: I think you want a double underscore: `attr_name + '__icontains':` there.

Comment: Missed that, Thanks ;-)